# Ошибка при установки программ "Install server not responding" - Windows 10

Tags: windows

При установке некоторых программ (конкретно, firmware для работы внешней звуковой карты Yamaha Steinberg UR12) вначале долго висит вот такое окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

потом, после нескольких часов, выводится это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Возможные шаги по устранению проблем:

1. Установка в режиме совместимости (Windows 7 и ниже). Если не прошло, начинаем идти от пункта к пункту:
2. Заходим в управление службами (можно через Пуск, я предпочитаю Win+R, ввести "services.msc"), ищем там службу "Установщик Windows" (Windows Installer в английской версии). Обычно он остановлен и запускается системой, но запуск его вручную помогает устранить некоторые ошибки инсталляции. Жмём "Запустить", перегружаем систему, пробуем установить программу заново.
3. Создаём нового пользователя, заходим в него, пробуем запустить программу установки заново. Если под другим пользователем всё установилось, с одной стороны, проблема решена, с другой, если первый пользователь вам нужен, придётся ремонтировать его экаунт. См. п. 4 и далее
4. Если два первых пункта не помогли, можно попробовать переустановить Установщик. Вот скрипт для запуска с правами администратора:

---

```
msiexec /unreg
msiexec /regserver
regsvr32.exe /s %windir%\system32\msi.dll
sc create msiserver start= auto binpath= “c:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe /V” displayname= “Windows Installer”
Net start msiserver
```

4. Качаем [Официальный фикс от Майкрософта](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed). Если честно, никогда не помогал :) Но есть люди, утверждающие, что он очень полезен. Поэтому привожу на всякий случай.
5. Если не помогли первые четыре пункта, пробуем отремонтировать хранилище компонентов. Скрипт:

---

```
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

Не забываем перегрузиться.

6. Ну, и напоследок - проверка системы:

---

```
sfc/scannow
```

С последующей перезагрузкой.

Подозреваю, что дальше - только переустановка системы. Но прежде чем её делать, попробуйте установить эти программы на свежепоставленную систему, возможно, у них конфликт с Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Была такая же проблема с установкой Ableton, помогло выключение Voicemeeter. Полагаю, что дело в конфликте драйверов или в чём-то подобном.